# Android: Reading files currently held by the OS (e.g., /dev/log/main, /dev/input/event*)

Tags: android, file, io

Files like `/dev/log/main`,  `/dev/input/event*` are always hold by the OS. If you cat the file , the end of the file will not show and new words will be appended to your "cat" results continuously.

When I use `new FileInputStream` to open such files, it always responds with permission denied (probably because they are being used by other purposes as I mentioned before).
Permission is not denied for files like `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Is there any way to read such files? I want to know whether there is any user input  from  `/dev/input/event*`.

Comment: Do you have the log reading permission in your Manifest?

Comment: @Joe Simpson    Yes. I have. Without that , I can not read my logcat result.

Comment: I think actually to read /dev/input/event* is to use root because otherwise you could easily snoop on people's passwords etc.

Comment: @Joe Simpson Sounds reasonable. But I only need to know whether there is new input or not. I do not need to read the details of the file. Maybe I could check whether the size of the file changes or not. Thanks for your reply；》

Comment: May I ask why? What kind of an app would need this kind of thing?

Comment: @ Joe Simpson  Oh.This is for my research. I want to record the user hehaviors so that I can predict something in the future for the purpose of saving power:>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux, unlike Windows, does not lock files just because some other process has them open. I just opened a shell on my HTC Desire, and had a look:

```
$ ls -l /dev/input
crw-rw---- root     input     13,  73 2012-03-02 19:19 event9
crw-rw---- root     input     13,  72 2012-03-02 19:19 event8
(etc)
```

As you can see, those files are only readable and writable by user “root” and group “input”.

Files like /proc/cpuinfo are deliberately world-readable because they contain information provided by the kernel to processes. In fact, none of the files in /proc are real files: the whole of /proc consists of entries that only exist in the kernel, not on disk.

Comment: Oh.Thx for your reply. So you mean I need to obtain root privilege before I can read them? I think probably that's the case. Then I think I need to give up this way because I don't want to get the root privilege:< Maybe there are other ways to track the user input without  root privilege...

Comment: @D'Oliveiro Hi,today I have checked the file/proc/cpuinfo                       $ ls -l /proc/cpuinfo
-r--r--r-- root     root            0 2012-04-22 19:19 cpuinfo          The result also shows that it can only be read by root. So I feel confused now...

Comment: @D'Oliveiro And even without root, at least I can 'cat' the file /dev/input/event*, doesn't this mean even the nonroot user can read those files?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the files on Android outside of /data/local require root permissions to view.  I can't remember what the default bin commands are on the devices but if you install BusyBox you can run ls -l in the directory and get a listing of the permissions required to access the file.

Most likely you will need to root the device you are on - this will add the "su" command to your bin directory so you can gain root shell access.

If you decide to do this and need to function programmatically here is a shell interface class you can include in your project to do so.

I hope this helps give some insight.

https://github.com/jjNford/android-shell

Comment: Thank you for your information. But I think I can open the file like "/proc/cpuinfo" successfully. I think the main reason why I can not open "/dev/input/event*" is because they are kept being used. There is no end of the file just like when you use the command logcat without "-d" .

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But it seems that I can only accept one answer:<

Comment: @HaoShen I think you should required root permission when open "/dev/input/event*". I had make a try before. I write test program with c, and attempt to open that file. This program work well if i start it in adb shell. However, if i call it from java application like this:      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", NULL, new File(test_program_path));
Then, it was failed when open "/dev/input/event*". I don't know why, but from this i am sure that the reason why you can't open "/dev/input/event*" mentioned in your question is not beacuse  they are kept being used, in fact, that is permission.